# Appending a DIV to another DIV using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am appending a div (with id "rep") to another div (maindiv) like this :

```
$('#maindiv').append($('#rep').html());
```

However I am wondering where should I place the rep DIV as I dont want to display the rep DIV till the append function is called.Any suggestion will be highly useful

Comment: You're not appending the DIV, you're copying its contents. Is that what you want? To append the DIV itself, use `$('#maindiv').append($('#rep'));`

Comment: If you don't want it to be visible until you append, hide it by setting CSS `display: none;`.

Comment: but it will also be hidden after appending.doesn't it ?

Comment: Yes, then use `.show()` after you append.

Answer (score 0):

you can make it invisible, e.g.

```
<div id='rep' style='display:none'>content to append to maindiv</div>
```